# Replacing a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a python code piece. The problem is I have a list of words that have to be replaced if they occur in the input string. Below are few samples of the words to be replaced:

```
block1 with block 1
block2 with block 2
block3 with block 3
sector1 with sector 1
sector2 with sector 2
phase1 with phase 1
pocket1 with pocket 1
```

and so on, this goes on for a lot of numbers.

I was wondering if I there is a regex that could detect these replace it. This ways I won't  need to maintain a dictionary of a lot words

Is it possible to do so in python?

Comment: Given your example, would the string `block4` be replaced with `block 4`, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your given example, you could capture what is before the digit in a capturing group and in the replacement use group 1 and add a whitespace like `\1 '`

[`\b([a-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/0RWNBt/2)

Which matches

- a word boundary `\b`
- capture one or more lowercase character one or more times in a capturing group `([a-z]+)`

[`Demo`](http://rextester.com/PHZG48835)

Comment: I like this one better, as I don't need to hard code the words

Answer (score 1):

Search for this regex

```
(?i)\b(block|sector|phase|pocket)(\d+)
```

and replace it with

```
\1 \2
```

***Regex Breakdown***

```
(?i) #Inline modifier for ignore case
\b #Word boundary
  ( #First Capturing group
   block|sector|phase|pocket #Match any of 4 words
  )
  ( #Second Capturing group
   \d+ #Match digits
  )
```

**Python Code**

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)\b(block|sector|phase|pocket)(\d+)', r'\1 \2', inputString)
```